# Configure multiple paths for an Openshift Route

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

I'd like to define in Openshift one route with multiple paths, each path forwarding to a different service. For example /pathA would forward requests to ServiceA , whilst /pathB would forward requests to ServiceB.

Is this possible in OpenShift? If not, what would be the recommended approach?

I have also read about route sharding, however I cannot say that I've grasped the concept clearly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to create multiple routes per each path. But it can add multiple paths to same hostname. It's a same result of one route with multiple path you said.
Refer [Path Based Routes](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/networking/routes.html#path-based-routes)
 for more details.

For `ServiceA`,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: route-path-a
spec:
  host: www.example.com
  path: "/patha"   
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: service-a
```

For `ServiceB`,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: route-path-b
spec:
  host: www.example.com
  path: "/pathb"   
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: service-b
```

Comment: Does this work even if the Services have multiple paths for different apis?
For example for ServiceA:  www.example.com/patha/apiA   and www.example.com/patha/apiB

Comment: `Routes` doe not aware whether or not the `Services` have multiple paths, it just forward the request to them through the path rules.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I implemented the routing using your approach, however I have come across a new problem. When sending the request to www.example.com/patha/apiA , the ServiceA will receive a request to /patha/apiA instead of just /apiA .

Comment: Do you expect the  just `/apiA` , when `/patha/apiA` is requested ?

Comment: Exactly, my service expects only /apiA .I consider /patha as being part of the service selector

Comment: Unfortunately, as I mentioned above, `Routes` just forward the requests to `Services` with the path requested as it is.

Comment: @DaeinPark, you could do something with the`haproxy.router.openshift.io/rewrite-target` [annotation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.10/networking/routes/route-configuration.html#nw-route-specific-annotations_route-configuration).